# ¿Cómo solucionar errores al desplazar el detalle del vídeo?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Al expandir el contenedor del cuerpo en **Introducción** muestra el contenido de todos los vídeos.

Ahora el error esta en expandir el detalle del vídeo del siguiente titulo del vídeo:

```
audio video audio video audio video +
```

Si dan clic en más detalle del vídeo, es decir en el **(+)** observaran que existen un desbordamiento un desorden total al hacer **expand** en el detalle del vídeo, la **vista previa** el **tiempo del vídeo** la imagen de **play** todo se desbordan se desplaza.

Ahora en el texto del detalle del vídeo no tiene un margen un width establecido el texto se oculta.

Al hacer responsive el detalle del texto no se muestra se oculta en su totalidad mostrando una cierta parte del texto.

> En esta imagen muestro los errores, al ejecutar mi código observaran el problema que he comentado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> La solución, Lo ideal lo deseado es que se muestre mi código de esta manera tal como muestro en esta **imagen**

¿Como puedo corregir los errores mencionados, solucionarlos tal como se muestra esta **imagen.** es lo que deseo aplicar a mi código?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código completo**

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.accordion').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
$this.next().removeClass('show');
$this.removeClass("active");
$this.next().slideUp(350);
  } else {
$this.addClass("active");

$this.parent().parent().find('.panel').removeClass('show');
$this.parent().parent().find('.panel').slideUp(350);
$this.next().toggleClass('show');
$this.next().slideToggle(350);
  }
});


$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
$this.next().removeClass('show');
$this.removeClass("active");

$this.next().slideUp(350);
  } else {
$this.addClass("active");

$this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
$this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
$this.next().toggleClass('show');
$this.next().slideToggle(350);
  }
  });});
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  display: none;
}

ul li a.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78);
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: .75em;
  border-radius: 0.15em;
  transition: background .3s ease;
}

ul li a.toggle:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.toogle {
  float: left;
}

.toggle:after {
  content: '\002B';
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.toggle.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.inner {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul .inner.show {
  /*display: block;*/
}

.label:empty {
  display: none;
}
.chapters {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.view {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.view li {
  padding: .5% 1%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.view li:hover{
  background:#f9f9f9;
}

.rows {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  /*justify-content:space-between;*/
}

.play { 
  padding-right: 10px;
  /*align-self:center;*/
}

.video-title {
  width:60%;
  white-space: normal !important;
}

.view-preview,.length {
  color: #000;
  text-align:center;
}

.view-preview{
  width:23%;
}

.length {
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Introducción</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="chapters">
<ul class="view">
  <li>
    <div class="rows">
      <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
      <div class="video-title"><a href="vid.mp4">audio video audio video audio video</a><span class="toggle"></span>
        <ul class="inner">
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.Integer varius est vitae iaculis suscipit. Integer sed rutrum lectus</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="view-preview"><a href="vid.mp4">&nbsp;Vista Previa</a></div>
      <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="rows">
      <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
      <div class="video-title"><a href="video2.mp4">audio video audio video audio video</a></div>
      <div class="view-preview"><a  href="video2.mp4">&nbsp;Vista Previa</a></div>
      <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Iba a colocarte una respuesta con un heigh con propiedad auto, pero he probado tu código y me muestra el resultado tal y como tu lo pides... la segunda imagen es el ejecutable de tu código verdad?

Comment: El problema con esta pregunta no está en la dificultad técnica, sino que está muy pobremente escrita. Por favor, edita el texto e intenta explicar mejor lo que quieres conseguir.Por ejemplo, en las dos primeras frases parece que faltan palabras o signos de puntuación. Si tu idioma nativo no es el español, prueba con stackoverflow en inglés.

Comment: Tal y como ha comentado @PabloLozano, por favor, intenta redactar mejor tu pregunta ya que no queda muy claro.

Comment: @J.Mick, el objetivo es que al hacerse responsive el link "vista previa" y el tiempo deben ocultarse, es asi??

Comment: pero en la 2da imagen, la parte del responsive (pantalla reducida) ya no se ve "vista previa" ni "02:20"?

Comment: Acabo de publica la respuesta, revisalo, eso se arregla solo quitando el css align-items:center; del class .row. Respecto al contenido del detalle del video no se esta ocultando, probé con tu mismo código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tu 2da imagen:

1. Tamaño normal.- Indicas que se desplaza. Segun tu código se desplaza el "boton play", "vista previa" y "02:20" se desplazan verticalmente.

**Solucion** (quitar align-items):

```
.rows {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;      
}
```

Para quitar la viñeta del `li` y luego alinearlo al margen:

```
.view li {
  padding: .5% 1%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  list-style:none;
}

.view ul {
    margin-left : -35px;
}
```

2. Tamaño reducido (responsive).- evitar "vista_previa" y "02:20" se sobrepongan

**Solucion**,

Opcion 1: cambiar css:

```
 .length {
   width:20%;
 }
```

Opcion 2: Según ve que se sobrepone cuando el contenedor toma aprox 440px, entonces:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeWindows);
function resizeWindows(){
    if(parseInt($('.view .rows').css('width').replace('px',''))<440){
      $('.length').css('width','20%');
    }else{
      $('.length').css('width','10%');
    }
}
```

Si he interpreta mal el objetivo, coméntame para ajustar mi respuesta.

1. Boton, vista previa y tiempo no se desplazaron verticalmente
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Vista Previa y tiempo ajustados en modo reducido (responsive)
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65266/discussion-on-answer-by-juliocpiro-como-solucionar-errores-al-desplazar-el-deta).

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.accordion').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
$this.next().removeClass('show');
$this.removeClass("active");
$this.next().slideUp(350);
  } else {
$this.addClass("active");

$this.parent().parent().find('.panel').removeClass('show');
$this.parent().parent().find('.panel').slideUp(350);
$this.next().toggleClass('show');
$this.next().slideToggle(350);
  }
});


$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
$this.next().removeClass('show');
$this.removeClass("active");

$this.next().slideUp(350);
  } else {
$this.addClass("active");

$this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
$this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
$this.next().toggleClass('show');
$this.next().slideToggle(350);
  }
  });});
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  display: none;
}

ul li a.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78);
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: .75em;
  border-radius: 0.15em;
  transition: background .3s ease;
}

ul li a.toggle:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.toogle {
  float: left;
}

.toggle:after {
  content: '\002B';
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.toggle.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.inner {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}

ul .inner.show {
  /*display: block;*/
}

.label:empty {
  display: none;
}
.chapters {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.view {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.view li {
  padding: .5% 1%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.view li:hover{
  background:#f9f9f9;
}

.rows {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  /*justify-content:space-between;*/
}

.play { 
  padding-right: 10px;
  /*align-self:center;*/
}

.video-title {
  width:60%;
  white-space: normal !important;
}

.view-preview,.length {
  color: #000;
  text-align:center;
}

.view-preview{
  width:23%;
}

.length {
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Introducción</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="chapters">
<ul class="view">
  <li>
    <div class="rows">
      <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
      <div class="video-title"><a href="vid.mp4">audio video audio video audio video</a><span class="toggle"></span>
        <ul class="inner">
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.Integer varius est vitae iaculis suscipit. Integer sed rutrum lectus</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="view-preview"><a href="vid.mp4">&nbsp;Vista Previa</a></div>
      <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="rows">
      <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
      <div class="video-title"><a href="video2.mp4">audio video audio video audio video</a></div>
      <div class="view-preview"><a  href="video2.mp4">&nbsp;Vista Previa</a></div>
      <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

No se sí te sirve esto:-

.inner {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}